# Can i add my current app to the In App Purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, in-app-purchase

I have two paid apps on app store.
I want to create one app for free and want to add those two paid apps in In App Purchase.
Is it possible? If yes then how can i do this?

Do i have to create those apps again or i can use the existing apps (or binary) for In App purchase.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it the way you want to.

You'll have to create a new app and include the functionality of those two apps in the new app . The in-app purchase will be used to unlock those features.

Answer (score 1):

iOS, Android, Symbian, Blackberry all have there allotted app stores.

In app purchasing is generally more risque. Unless you link them to an account of some sort. So I reckon that you keep that interface to the Apple Store, but, it's very possible to do.

Here's a short tutorial: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/